# About present participle and past participle

Tags: participles

What is present and past participle?

I get confused by these sentences for example:

> - I saw the pen keeping on the table.
> - I saw the pen kept on the table.

But at the moment the pen is on the table, so which of the sentences above are correct?

Comment: The first sentence is incorrect because you need a modal verb to form a progressive clause *I saw the pen **was** keeping on the table*

Comment: What is modal verb and how to use could you share some more details

Comment: if you couldn't understand it. Try do research :)

Comment: Ok so when we say ● there is a book keeping on the table. instead of that.  ●we have to say there is a book is keeping on the table means the book is on the table at the moment while speaking or we can say both of sentance above

Comment: 178049's suggestion is perhaps misleading, because it contains an implied _that_ (_I saw [that] the pen was keeping_) and because no one would say that anyway.

Answer (score 1):

These participles are not only present and past, they are also active and passive respectively.  If you keep a pen, the pen is kept.  To apply an active participle (*keeping*) to the pen is to suggest that the pen is there by its own choice.

Are you using *keep* here as a synonym of *stay, remain*?  It does mean that in a few idiomatic usages (especially "keep quiet" and "keep [continue] doing"), but not in others, at least in General American dialect; I would not say that my cat *keeps* on his favorite chair.

**Added much later:** Though that would explain why some people mis-hear *kipping* as *keeping* in the sentence *The Norwegian Blue prefers kipping on its back.*

Comment: This is exactly right. The first is wrong only because the pen cannot *keep* on the table (in standard English, anyway). But it can be *kept* there by the family or whoever.